# Injective homomorphism $H:C_b(X) \to C_b(Y)$ implies the existence of a continuous and surjective map $F:Y \to X$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, algebras

Let $X$ and $Y$ be $2$ topological spaces and let $C_b(X)$ and $C_b(Y)$ denote the set of all continuous and bounded functions on X and Y, respectively, to the space of complex numbers. It is a well-known fact that $C_b(X)$ and $C_y(Y)$ are $C^*$ algebras (under the usual operations: pointwise addition, pointwise multiplication, pointwise scalar multiplication, sup norm, and the star operation being conjugation)

The following theorem is rather easy to show:

**Theorem:** If there exists a continuous and surjective map $F:Y \to X$, then there exists an injective $*$-homomorphim $H:C_b(X) \to C_b(Y)$.

One can just define $H(f)=f \circ F$ and show that this $H$ has the desired properties.

I am interested in the converse, namely:

**Question:** If there exists an injective $*$-homomorphim $H:C_b(X) \to C_b(Y),$ does there exist a continuous and surjective map $F:Y \to X?$ How should one define $F?$

Recall that a $*$-homomorphism is an algebra homomorphism that also preserves the norm and the star operation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**PS**. If you are not familiar with $C^*$ algebras, then disregard that part of the question and regard this problem as a question about algebras.

Comment: The ring structure on $C(X)$ completely determines the space $X$... I don't recall the deal with the smaller bounded functions ring. But the first would allow you to go back in the case of ring homomorphisms, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not without additional hypotheses on the spaces $X$ and $Y$.  For instance, let $Y$ be a single point and let $X$ be an indiscrete space (or any other space with no non-constant complex-valued functions) with more than one point.  Then $C_b(X)\cong C_b(Y)\cong\mathbb{C}$, but there does not exist any surjection $Y\to X$.

It is true if you assume $X$ and $Y$ are compact Hausdorff.  In that case, by Gelfand duality, $X$ is canonically homeomorphic to the space of $*$-homomorphisms $C_b(X)\to\mathbb{C}$ (with the topology of pointwise convergence), by identifying $x\in X$ with the $*$-homomorphism given by evaluation at $x$, and similarly for $Y$.  Any $*$-homomorphism $H:C_b(X)\to C_b(Y)$ induces a continuous map $F:Y\to X$ by composition: take a point of $Y$, consider it as a $*$-homomorphism to $\mathbb{C}$, compose it with $H$ to get a $*$-homomorphism $C_b(X)\to\mathbb{C}$, and then identify this $*$-homomorphism with an element of $X$.  Note that conversely, $H$ can similarly be recovered from $F$ by composition: $H$ is the map $C_b(X)\to C_b(Y)$ which takes a function on $X$ and composes it with $F$ to get a function on $Y$.  (All of this is part of Gelfand duality, which says the functor $C_b$ gives an equivalence of categories between the category of compact Hausdorff spaces and the opposite category of commutative unital C*-algebras.)

In particular, if $H$ is injective, this means that a continuous function on $X$ is uniquely determined by its composition with $F$.  This implies that $F$ is surjective (otherwise by Urysohn's lemma there would exist a nonzero continuous function on $X$ which vanishes on the proper closed subset $F(Y)$).

If $X$ is an arbitrary space, then $C_b(X)$ is naturally isomorphic to $C_b(\beta X)$, where $\beta X$ is the Stone-Cech compactification of $X$.  So if $X$ and $Y$ are arbitrary topological spaces, all we can get from an injective $*$-homomorphism $C_b(X)\to C_b(Y)$ is a continuous surjection $\beta Y\to \beta X$.

Comment: Seems to me that recently you have been the only one answering my questions :) And as always, you are extremely thorough. What books/papers have you used to learn this part of functional analysis (namely, Gelfand-Naimark duality for spaces of the form $C_b(X)$ and the connection of Gelfand Naimark theorem to obtaining compactifications of topological spaces as well as its connection to the Stone-Cech compactifications). I am looking for a good reference, so that I won't need to waste your time anymore :)

Comment: Hmmm, I don't really know a good definitive reference.  A lot of this stuff I just gradually picked up on my own from idle speculation or from passing references in lots of places.  I believe I originally learned the most basic theory of Gelfand duality from some very nice unpublished notes by Nik Weaver which I think he has since turned into a textbook _Measure Theory and Functional Analysis_ (the relevant parts being sections 3.5-3.7).  But I think that only talks about the case of locally compact Hausdorff spaces.

Comment: I have heard that the book _Rings of continuous functions_ by Gillman and Jerison is an authoritative reference for a lot of questions like this, but I haven't actually read it myself so I can't say for sure how much it addresses the particular questions you are asking.

Comment: I'm a fan of Rings of continuous functions (and I have it and read most of it). But it only deals with the ring structure, not the algebra structure or the norm etc. It's very much a general topology book. The theory basically covers all Tychonoff spaces (who have enough continuous functions to start with). The Cech-Stone compactification plays a big rôle, and real-compactifications etc.